# Pulling oracle jdbc driver from local nexus repository through ivy -> tries to hit external source?

Tags: grails, maven, ivy, nexus

I'm behind a proxy, and I'm trying to grab a jar from my local nexus repository that I added manually. Why does grails/ivy try to connect outward when I try to download the jar?

```
...
Downloading: MYURL/ojdbc16-11.1.0.7.0.jar.sha1 ...
Download complete.
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-ojdbc16/tags/RELEASE_11_1_0_7_0/grails-ojdbc16-11.1.0.7.0.jar
```

Dependency config:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
    runtime 'com.oracle:ojdbc16:11.1.0.7.0'
}
```

Repos:

```
   repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenRepo "MYSERVER/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty"
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mysteriously no longer happens. I did switch back to 1.3.6 for other reasons, but I'm not sure why this ever occurred.